# Get URL from Link not visible in Chrome Dev Tools Element Tab

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am not certain of the best way to ask this question. In short, I am using puppeteer to get data from a table. I can see and click on a link in the table, but I cannot see a link with an href value in the devtools. How can I retrieve the link address?

When you click on the link it opens a new tab.

The following code will open the first student's tab.

```js
 const [popup] = await Promise.all([
        new Promise(resolve => page.once('popup', resolve)),
        page.click('.major-student-name'),

\\Something here to get the address of the opened page\\

      ]);
```

I really don't even want to open the page. I just want all the param values of the links for each student. The page.click method only performs the method on the first selector matching the provided selector name.

I've been able to get the rest of the data I need with page.evaluate() and cheerio

[image]

When I inspect  the element all I see is the text without a link. I'm guessing it's purposefully hidden from the devtools. How do I access it?

Here's a picture of what I see in the devtools.

[image]

Comment: I think that "clickable text" is not a link with an href value. It's just a javascript calling functions. Does the URL really change when you click the student name?

Comment: @EdiImanto Thank you for helping me clarify my question. It opens up a new tab connected to the student's page.

Comment: @SabrinaDanielleGreen you can override the `window.open` function to collect the urls rather than navigating to them. then click on each name and you'll end up with a list of all urls.

Comment: @mbit I will try that, thanks for your suggestion!